# How do I tell VSCode that I don't have/don't want a PHP executable?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, settings

I'm using VSCode to update an internal/hobbyist website that uses PHP.  I don't have a php executable on the computer I am using to do the work (and I don't want to add one either), and anyway the website itself is going to be deployed on another computer.  But when I go to edit a php file, I get this popup:

[image]

Of course in the PHP settings the path to the executable is blank.

[image]

I think that this popup only occurs the first time that I edit a file after loading the workspace.  But I don't want to see it ever.

Won't someone rid me of this turbulent popup<sup>1</sup>?

<sup>1. A thinly veiled attempt at [historical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_no_one_rid_me_of_this_turbulent_priest%3F) humor</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I would encapsulate the above code in a try catch

```
try
{
[above code]
}
catch
{
//do nothing
}}
```